# .NET Itemtemplate repeater?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, css

Im working on a website built in .net

the following code

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RT_FAQ" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<div class="faq-row" style="z-index: 976;">
   <span class="itp-title"><a href="#" onclick="showhide('div1');"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Question")%></a></span>
    <div id="div1" style="display: none;"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Answer")%></div>
</div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

outputs something along the lines of...

```
<div class="faq-row" style="z-index: 976;">
    <span class="itp-title">Title</span>
    <div id="div1" style="display: none;">Div contents</div>
</div>
<div class="faq-row" style="z-index: 976;">
    <span class="itp-title">Title</span>
    <div id="div1" style="display: none;">Div contents</div>
</div>
<div class="faq-row" style="z-index: 976;">
    <span class="itp-title">Title</span>
    <div id="div1" style="display: none;">Div contents</div>
</div>
<div class="faq-row" style="z-index: 976;">
    <span class="itp-title">Title</span>
    <div id="div1" style="display: none;">Div contents</div>
</div>
```

If you see all the divs are being given id="div1". I need to somehow give them all unique ID's so the first is div1, second div2 and so on.

Is this possible with .net?

Comment: Why do you want to give them all unique IDs?  Do you intend on referencing them somehow?

Comment: Im writing a JS script that shows the div when the span itp-title is clicked so they need to be unique...

Comment: leandre_b has the answer below, but given your comment you could also try using jQuery to toggle the visibility of the div that is a sibling to the span that was clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the ItemIndex :

```
<div id="div<%# Container.ItemIndex %>" style="display: none;"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Answer")%></div>
```

Just add `+ 1` if you want to start at `1` instead of `0`.